# If $A$ is the matrix that represents a linear operator $T$ then, $A^{-1}$ is the matrix that represents $T^{-1}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Let $T$ be a linear operator from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $A$ be its representing matrix with the basis $v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n$.
Then
$$T(v_j) = \sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij}\ v_i $$
where $a_{ij} = A_{ij}$.

Let $B$ be the matrix that represents $T^{-1}$ with the basis $v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n$.
Then
$$ T^{-1}(v_j) = \sum_{i=1}^n b_{ij}\ v_i$$
where $b_{ij} = B_{ij}$.

Now
\begin{align}T(T^{-1}(v_j)) &= T\left(\sum_{i=1}^n b_{ij}\ v_i\right) = \sum_{i=1}^n b_{ij}\ T(v_i)\\ 
&= \sum_{i=1}^n\ b_{ij}\sum_{k=1}^n\ a_{ki}\ v_i\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^nb_{kj}\ a_{ik}\ v_i = v_j.
\end{align}
Since $v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n$ is linearly independent, from the last summation of the last equation, if $i=j$, the sum of $b_{kj}\ a_{ik} = 1$ and if $i \neq j$ it is $0$. Which means the $j$th row of matrix $B$ and $i$th column of $A$ equals $1$ only if $i=j$.

Now if we change the order of $T$ and $T^{-1}$ in above, then $j$th row of $A$ and $i$th column of $B$ gives $1$ only if $i = j$. Which means $AB = BA = I$, and thus $B=A^{-1}$, and thus proof is done.

Am I right?

Comment: How are you going about swapping the indices on $a$ and $b$ from the second to last line to the last line? I'm not following that.